Design: Single or Multiple Nodes For Robot Behaviors
I have built a docking node for my GoPiGo3 robot which offers /dock and /undock services.  The docking node currently goes straight to the robot hardware for the docking/undocking commands which at this time are to use the robot hardware intrinsic drive_cm() to move 17 cm forward or backward.
This design has two nodes (docking, and ros2_gopigo3_node) talking to the robot hardware.  This really simplifies the programming, but perhaps is bad design.
I can think of some other design models:

GoPiGo3 node could expose the drive_cm(blocking) as a service for the docking node to use


Advantage: only one node ever talking to hardware
Disadvantage: Complicates node to manage simultaneous callbacks


docking node could use /cmd_vel twist to command the motion and subscribe to /motor_encoder/left and right to stop motion after desired travel


Advantage: only one node talking to hardware
Disadvantage: Need to manage simultaneous callbacks, embeds "drive_cm service" without offering it for other nodes


Create "DriveCM Node" that offers the service and uses /cmd_vel twist and the encoders (or perhaps /odometry)


Advantage: only one node talking to hardware
Advantage" simplifies other (future) behaviors that might need to drive a distance

Of course there are other designs (e.g. use SLAM and Nav2), but at this point my robot is just undocking a known distance, and returning that distance to dock, and I don't trust the /odometry the bot is publishing.
